# pandas - Convert split a cell with multiple values and insert new rows for each value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First of all, apologies for the title, I can't really describe this well in title.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[123,124,125,126], 
               ['FX10', 'FX11', 'FX12', 'FX15'],
               [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['X', 'Y'], None, [1]],
             ]).T
df.columns = ['ID', 'Type', 'Multiple']
```

[image]

I want to convert the above table into something like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: explode is what you are after

Comment: `df.explode('Multiple')`

Comment: @DaniMesejo appreciate the help! saved me a ton of time having to do it manually by writing codes... I didn't know there was a built-in function